# Deserializing a class from a third party library

Tags: java, gson

What is the recommended way to deserialize a JSON which maps to a implementation class in a 3rd party library? The library returns only the class's interface to the users , so there is no way for gson to construct the object without me supplying the name of the implementation class. Problem is if the library's method that returns the object changes the implementation class, it will break the deserialization code.

```
Class CustomAddress {

private Address localAddress;

}
```

Address is an interface, localAddress being set with return value from the library.

Comment: You might be able to leverage [GWT's Autobean framework](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideAutoBeans.html), as it is designed for exactly this - mapping JSON to JavaBean-like `interface` definitions. But it might also be overkill, depending on how complex your data structure is it might be easier just to create the classes yourself...

Comment: Thank you Boris,yes it is a overkill, its only needed in one place. The only option I can think of is creating an object again using the library and find out the classname from the returned object.

Comment: I don't see why you need to do that. Create a simple JavaBean that implements the `interface`. Done.

Comment: Not sure I understand the comment. Can you give simple sample code?

Comment: Consider whether or not to tie the JSON directly to the 3rd party.  As you stated any change to the 3rd party will require the server to be changed.  But also all **clients** which generate the JSON would also have to change.